# Переклад слова disadvantage

Tags: переклад, from-english, вибір-слова

Який переклад можна підібрати до слова **disadvantage** в значінні "**несприятливі умови, невигідне становище**", тільки їдним словом? Наприклад, прийшли 2 людей на співбесіду. В одного - **перевага**, він молодий, досвід є, успіхи і все таке. А один до сього ніде не працював. В нього - **антиперевага**. То як нормально вот се сказати? **Недолік**, **вразливість** і **слабкість** не підходять. Найліпше, що я знаходив - **невигідність**, однак воно теж не дуже підходить. Невже нема в українській мові слів з саме таким значінням?

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка, чому саме не підходять слова, які ви перелічили. Це може вплинути на відповідь.

Answer (score 3):

Добрий день.

Можна спробувати слово **вада**. "Його вадою була відсутність досвіду".

На думку спадаює ще кілька слів:

- *прогалина*
- *упущення*

Answer (score 1):

У такому випадку можна сказати «мінусом його кандидатури є те, що...» або «мінусом його як кандидата є те, що...».

Answer (score -1):

> *Недолік* Джона в тому, що він досі ніде не працював.

<sup>Буду радий допомогти з іншими прикладами.</sup>